# How to solve raise Validation Error(_('Invalid model name in action definition.') in odoo 12 module creation

Tags: python, debugging, module, odoo-12

I want to create "School" module in odoo 12 in windows 10. I have created all require file like 
**init**.py, **manifest**.py, model/_init__.py, model/_init__.py, model/student.py, views/student_view.xml"

My code sample given bellow

**init**.py

```
import model
```

**manifest**.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
    'name': 'School',
    'version': '12.0.1.0.0',
    'summary': 'Record Student Information',
    'category': 'Tools',
    'author': 'Niyas Raphy',
    'maintainer': 'Cybrosys Techno Solutions',
    'company': 'Cybrosys Techno Solutions',
    'website': 'https://www.cybrosys.com',
    'depends': ['base'],
    'data': [
        'views/student_view.xml'
    ],
    'images': [],
    'license': 'AGPL-3',
    'installable': True,
    'application': False,
    'auto_install': False,
}
```

model/_init__.py

```
from. import student
```

model/student.py

```
from odoo import models, fields

 class StudentStudent(models.Model):
    _name = 'student.student'

    name = fields.Char(string='Name', required=True)
```

views/student_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="student_menu_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Students</field>
            <field name="res_model">student.student</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="domain">[]</field>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create The First Student
                </p>
            </field>
</record>
        <menuitem id="school_menu"
                name="School"/>
        <menuitem id="school_student_menu" parent="school_menu" name="Student"/>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

When i install into odoo 12 then facing issue like 
 raise ValidationError(_('Invalid model name %r in action definition.') % action.res_model)
Here is the error

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 758, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 663, in _tag_record
    record = model.with_context(rec_context)._load_records([data], self.mode == 'update')
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\models.py", line 3865, in _load_records
    records = self._load_records_create([data['values'] for data in to_create])
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\models.py", line 3779, in _load_records_create
    return self.create(values)
  File "<decorator-gen-37>", line 2, in create
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\api.py", line 452, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "f:\odoo\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_actions.py", line 238, in create
    return super(IrActionsActWindow, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-35>", line 2, in create
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\api.py", line 452, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "f:\odoo\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_actions.py", line 59, in create
    res = super(IrActions, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in create
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\api.py", line 452, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\models.py", line 3560, in create
    records = self._create(data_list)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\models.py", line 3692, in _create
    records._validate_fields(name for data in data_list for name in data['stored'])
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\models.py", line 1108, in _validate_fields
    check(self)
  File "f:\odoo\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_actions.py", line 141, in _check_model
    raise ValidationError(_('Invalid model name %r in action definition.') % action.res_model)
odoo.exceptions.ValidationError: ("Invalid model name 'student' in action definition.", None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\http.py", line 656, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\http.py", line 698, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\http.py", line 346, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\http.py", line 941, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "f:\odoo\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 966, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "f:\odoo\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 954, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\api.py", line 749, in call_kw
    return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\api.py", line 736, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-61>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "f:\odoo\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 74, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "f:\odoo\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 445, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "f:\odoo\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 561, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 421, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 313, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 222, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package, report=report)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 68, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 802, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 865, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 755, in parse
    self.parse(rec, mode)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 764, in parse
    exc_info[2]
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 86, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 758, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 663, in _tag_record
    record = model.with_context(rec_context)._load_records([data], self.mode == 'update')
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\models.py", line 3865, in _load_records
    records = self._load_records_create([data['values'] for data in to_create])
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\models.py", line 3779, in _load_records_create
    return self.create(values)
  File "<decorator-gen-37>", line 2, in create
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\api.py", line 452, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "f:\odoo\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_actions.py", line 238, in create
    return super(IrActionsActWindow, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-35>", line 2, in create
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\api.py", line 452, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "f:\odoo\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_actions.py", line 59, in create
    res = super(IrActions, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in create
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\api.py", line 452, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\models.py", line 3560, in create
    records = self._create(data_list)
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\models.py", line 3692, in _create
    records._validate_fields(name for data in data_list for name in data['stored'])
  File "F:\Odoo\server\odoo\models.py", line 1108, in _validate_fields
    check(self)
  File "f:\odoo\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_actions.py", line 141, in _check_model
    raise ValidationError(_('Invalid model name %r in action definition.') % action.res_model)
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Invalid model name 'student' in action definition.
None" while parsing file:/f:/odoo/server/odoo/addons/school/views/student_view.xml:4, near
<record id="student_menu_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Students</field>
            <field name="res_model">student</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="domain">[]</field>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create The First Student
                </p>
            </field>
</record>
```

Please help me how to solve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: it seems your xml not updated properly

Comment: in traceback it say '<field name="res_model">student</field>' but in your xml it define it as '<field name="res_model">student.student</field>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put model res_model as "student" but your model name is student.student that's why it gave you error of invalid model defination.